# Code not working - getting a figure with no plot

Tags: matlab, debugging, plot

Why is this simple code not working properly? I have dozens of other more complex codes based on the same template as this one, and they run faster as well, but it's just not working. I have spent hours trying to fix this.

I should have `size(y) = 1001 x 11` and a graph, not just a point. Also, the warning

`Failure at t=1.194435e+02.  Unable to meet integration tolerances without reducing the step size below the smallest value allowed (2.273737e-13) at time t`

doesn't shed light on this.

Here is the script `AB.m`:

```
global Q q l v1 v2 v3 v4
v3 = 0.00086;
v4 = 0.000086;
D0 = 0.01;
Q = 0.01;
q = 0.001;
l = 0.001;
v1 = 0.999;
v2 = 0.999;
K0 = 1;
P0 = 1;
S10 = 100;
y0 = [S10 zeros(1,7) K0 P0 D0];
tf = 1e10;
tvec = 0:tf/1e3:tf; 

options = odeset('RelTol',1e-4);
[t,y] = ode15s(@ABEqns,tvec,y0,options);
S1 = y(:,1);
S2 = y(:,2);
KS1 = y(:,3);
PS2 = y(:,4);
DS1 = y(:,5);
DS2 = y(:,6);
DKS1 = y(:,7);
DPS2 = y(:,8);
K = y(:,9);
P = y(:,10);
D = y(:,11);
Stot = S1+S2+KS1+PS2+DS1+DS2+DKS1+DPS2;

plot(t,Stot,'k','LineSmoothing','on')
axis([0 tf 0 1.1*max(Stot)])
xlabel('Time (s)')
hold on
```

Here is the function `ABEqns.m`:

```
function ydot = ABEqns(t,y)
global Q q l v1 v2 v3 v4
S1 = y(1);
S2 = y(2);
KS1 = y(3);
PS2 = y(4);
DS1 = y(5);
DS2 = y(6);
DKS1 = y(7);
DPS2 = y(8);
K = y(9);
P = y(10);
D = y(11);

ydot = zeros(11,1);
ydot(1) = Q+l*(DS1+KS1)-q*S1*(D+K)+v2*PS2;
ydot(2) = l*(DS2+PS2)-q*S2*(D+P)+v1*KS1;
ydot(3) = l*(DKS1-KS1)+q*(K*S1-D*KS1);
ydot(4) = l*(DPS2-PS2)+q*(P*S2-D*PS2);
ydot(5) = q*D*S1-(l+v3)*DS1;
ydot(6) = q*D*S2-(l+v4)*DS2;
ydot(7) = q*D*KS1-(l+v3)*DKS1;
ydot(8) = q*D*PS2-(l+v4)*DPS2;
ydot(9) = (l+v1)*KS1-q*K*S1+v3*DKS1;
ydot(10) = (l+v2)*PS2-q*P*S2+v4*DPS2;
ydot(11) = (l+v3)*(DS1+DKS1)+(l+v4)*(DS2+DPS2)-q*D*(S1+S2+KS1+PS2);
end
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The warning tells you exactly what is happening. Your derivative is blowing up at t=119.4435, so either the ODE doesn't have a solution valid over the whole of `tvec`, or the error in `ode15s` causes the solution trajectory to become unbounded.

Comment: What is the suggested recourse? I have never seen this.

Comment: Either your problem doesn't have a continuous solution, your code isn't solving the problem you think you are solving, or `ode15s` isn't capable of finding a good enough solution (unlikely). You could try other ODE solvers such as `ode45`, but they are unlikely to help.

Comment: "Your code isn't solving the problem you think you are solving" Excellent. I made a mistake in my ODEs. The code works just fine now.

Comment: Cool, it's easily done!